# MFMessageComposeViewController does not show up send button and message body on ios8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

MFMessageComposeViewController does not show up send button and message body on ios8, when tapping on recipient list keyboard comes up and also send button,message body shows up. Below is the code for message functionality :

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *msgController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] ;
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
     if (msgController)
      {
           msgController = nil;
           msgController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] ;
      }
NSString *messageBody =@"helloWorld";
msgController.body = messageBody;
msgController.recipients = numberArray;
msgController.messageComposeDelegate = (id)self;
[self presentViewController:msgController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all add MessageUI framework to your app frameworks and then

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
@interface class() 
<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
{
....
}
@end
```

Then in your class implementation write

```
     if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
     {
         MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
         [mail setMailComposeDelegate:self];
         [mail setSubject:@"Subject goes here..."];
         [mail setMessageBody:@"Message body goes here..." isHTML:NO];
         [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
     }
```

and also implement the delegate for MFMailcomposeViewController as like

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I am talking about sms feature, which involves MFMessageComposeViewController, not mail.

Comment: Hi, you can check this link for both Mail & Message its also working with the iOS8 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MessageComposer/Listings/MessageComposerViewController_m.html

Answer (score 0):

There should be recipient and some message in the body to enable the "Send" button.

Here is the link for reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendinganSMSMessage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010416-SW1

http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/how-to-send-an-sms-progammatically.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you have checked the code snipped I provided, I have already given recipients & body, and they weren't empty..

Comment: So does the composer which appears on the screen have the send button OR the save button is disabled?

Comment: No,it contains only the recipient textField and cancel button, when tapping on the recipient textField keyboard comes up and send button,and message body appears .

Comment: Can you send me a screenshot of your device for the same issue?

Comment: Hey @Saptarshi did u find the solution? i am facing the same issue but couldn't figure out the problem